# must be of type string, bool given in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I  am working on laravel(version 9.9) on ubuntu server. My composer version is 2.4. Every thing was going good before. When I try to run composer install it shows me error

`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, bool given in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php:194 Stack trace:`

I just installed  php-stripe library, that works  fine on localhost and raises problem on production server.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error happens when the reading of the composer.json fails for some reason. Try updading your composer to the newest version (currently 2.5) because that seems to have added a clearer error message.

Comment: @apokryfos problem is that same error arises on every command of Composer like composer update, composer self-update, composer install, whatever the command is, same error arises instantly.

Comment: are you using version control like git? try to checkout to previous commits that changes/updates the composer.json or composer.lock and then run composer install until you can see which commit causes this issue.

Comment: This does not fixes your issue but it will show you which commit causes this problem. From there, you may/may not be able to know what causes the issue in the first place.

Comment: It looks like you use Composer that is provided by your system, that can be outdated. You can install it locally instead: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally